# How to use ClickOnce to deploy my C#(4.0)Visual studio 2010 windows form based Application?

Tags: c#, .net

We are developing C# 4.0 windows based application using visual studio 2010. Now we want to make an installable version of the exe using clickonce to deploy our application. I am new to .NET platform. So, please give me a step by step procedure to use clickonce to deploy my application.

While following steps :What should i need to given in Installation Folder URL Box(2 nd text Box):
[image]

Comment: From msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31kztyey.aspx

Comment: how will you deploy your app? will you use a file share, web location or media like usb/Cd-rom?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the break down of the two paths in this wizard

- Publish Folder - Where should the Publish process put the ClickOnce deployment package
- Installation Folder - Where will users of the application go to install the application from

Often times these are the same location.  For example when I deploy ClickOnce applications internally I publish to a network share.  This is the same place where users go to install the application.

One scenario where they would be different is when the users install from a web location.  In that scenario you'd often have a publish folder which was a network share or path on the local computer while the installation folder was a web site URL

Comment: Thanks a lot JaredPar!, Shall i give C:\program files in installation folder.If i give like that it raising "The String must be fully qualified URL or UNC Path" what i do for it?

Comment: @Saravanan I didn't realize it was constrained to a UNC path.  You'll probably need to do something like `\\mycomputername\c$\Program Files\"

Comment: suppose, my computer name is saravanan.If i give \\saravanan\c$\Program Files\ Then Is it Work on my colleague System? For example i am going to install to his machine?

Comment: @saravanan if you want to install to multiple machines you should pick a central network share to publish to.

Comment: @JaredPar:Actually My Application is Windows Form based Application.No need to access another computer.Once installed on the machine it work with in the PC itself.So, What i Do?

Comment: @Saravanan in that case i would just put it in a place like `c:\users\public` and let every user individually click on it to install it.

Comment: @ JaredPar: For that i mentioned C:\program files\.But it says "The String must be fully qualified URL or UNC Path" how i put it?